# JSON and PHP in android

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

i try to finish my program wth JSON
this my program

```
package udin.tes2;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;




import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class LihatInfo extends Activity {

   TextView error,br1;
   String i,id_kepadatan,returnString;


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

   @Override


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.lihat_info);

        br1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_error);





   }

   public void clickHandler(View view){
    Intent a = null;
    id_kepadatan = "5";
    switch (view.getId()){
    case R.id.lihatInfo:

ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id_kepadatan", id_kepadatan));


/*            String valid = "1";*/      

        String response = null;

        try {

           response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/android/cek.php", postParameters);


           String result = response.toString();  
           //parse json data

              try{
                      returnString = "";


                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                      for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){

                              JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                              Log.i("log_tag","id_kepadatan: "+json_data.getInt("id_kepadatan")+
                                      ", username: "+json_data.getString("username")+
                                      ", nama_jalan: "+json_data.getString("nama_jalan")+
                                      ", status: "+json_data.getString("status")+
                                      ", tanggal: "+json_data.getString("tanggal")+
                                      ", waktu: "+json_data.getString("waktu")+
                                      ", keterangan: "+json_data.getString("keterangan")
                              );

                              //Get an output to the screen
                              returnString += "\n" + json_data.getString("nama_jalan") + " -> "+ json_data.getString("status")+ " pada "+ json_data.getString("tanggal")+ " waktu "+ json_data.getString("waktu")+ " karena "+ json_data.getString("keterangan");
                      }
              }


              catch(JSONException e){
                      Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
              }

              try{


               br1.setText(returnString);


              }


              catch(Exception e){

               Log.e("log_tag","Error in Display!" + e.toString());;          

              }   

         }

               catch (Exception e) {

          Log.e("log_tag","Error in http connection!!" + e.toString());     

         }
        break;

   case R.id.kembali2:
        a = new Intent(this, Menu.class);
        startActivity(a);
        break;
}
   }


}
```

and this my lihatInfo.php file

```
<?php
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("proyek akhir");

$query = "SELECT * FROM kepadatan WHERE  id_kepadatan > '". $_POST["id_kepadatan"]."'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
$output[]=$row;
print(json_encode($output));
mysql_close();
?>
```

but when i deploy to emulator, it says

"Error in Display!Java.lang.NullPointerException"

Can you help me? i only have 2 days to finish this
please help me....Thank You

Comment: are your sure you want an int here json_data.getInt("status")

Comment: i change it to String and it works!!
but what about "Error in Display!Java.lang.NullPointerException"??
because that is one problem left.....
Can you help me please?

Comment: i dont understand how....can you give me some clue to stop me using mysql_function?
thanks before :)

Comment: Your code is insecure.  You are wide open to SQL injection attacks and you **will be hacked** if you haven't been already.  Consider using prepared queries with PDO to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the error lies here

```
Log.i("log_tag","id_kepadatan: "+json_data.getInt("id_kepadatan")+
                                  ", username: "+json_data.getString("username")+
                                  ", nama_jalan: "+json_data.getString("nama_jalan")+
                       >>>>>>>>   ", status: "+json_data.getInt("status")+
                                  ", tanggal: "+json_data.getString("tanggal")+
                                  ", waktu: "+json_data.getString("waktu")+
                                  ", keterangan: "+json_data.getString("keterangan")
                          );
```

You might wana change it to getString

Comment: thank you.....i change it to String and it works!!
but i have 1 problem more that "Error in Display!Java.lang.NullPointerException"??
can you help me please?

Comment: great, could you accept the answer now

Comment: i just accept the answers....thanks :)

Comment: are you still getting the null pointer exception?

Comment: yes....can you help me please sir?
i will much appreciate it :)

Comment: please update you question with the stack trace of the error.

Comment: I need the stack trace from logcat not the layout xml!!

Comment: i'm sorry i can't post image because i'm newbie
but thanks for your help sir...God Bless You :)